# Get Non Empty Columnin Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the following pandas dataframe there are missing values in different columns for each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

d = {'col1': [1, 2, None], 'col2': [None, 4, 5], 'col3': [3, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I know I can use this to locate which columns are not empty in the ith row

```
df.iloc[0].notnull()
```

And then something like the following to find which specific columns are not empty.

```
np.where(df.iloc[0].notnull())
```

However, how can I then use those values as indices to return the non missing columns in the ith row?

For example, in the 0th row I'd like to return back columns

```
df.iloc[0, [0,2]]
```

This isn't quite right, but I'm guessing is somewhere along these lines?

```
df.iloc[0, np.where(df.iloc[0].notnull())]
```

** Edit
I realize I can do this

```
df.iloc[0, np.where(df.iloc[0].notnull())[0].tolist()]
```

And this returns the expected result. However, is this the most efficient approach?

Comment: Simply use `df.stack().loc[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

```
# set row number
row_number = 0

# get dataframe
df.loc[row_number, ~np.isnan(df.values)[row_number]]
```